# Getting a countable set from an uncountable set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am a bit confused with the proof of the following proposition (taken from Royden's Real Analysis - 3rd edition page 26).

$\textbf{Proposition}:$ There is an uncountable set $X$ which is well ordered by a relation $<$ in such a way that:

1) There is a last element $\Omega \in X$

2) If $x\in X$ and $x \neq\Omega$, then the set $\{y\in X:y<x\}$ is countable.

Proof: Let $Y$ be any uncountable set, say the one given by Problem 23. By the well ordering principle, there is a well ordering $<$ for $Y.$ If $Y$ does not have a last element, take an element $\alpha \notin Y,$ replace $Y$ by $Y\cup\{\alpha\},$ and extend the order $<$ by setting $y<\alpha$ for all $y\in Y$. This new $Y$ has a last element and is well ordered by $<.$ The set of $y$ in $Y$ for which the set $\{x \in Y : x<y\}$ is uncountable is a nonempty set, since it contains the last element of $Y.$ Let $\Omega$ be the smallest element in this set, and let $X=\{x \in Y : x< \Omega \textrm{ or } x= \Omega\}.$ Then $X$ is the required set.

My confusion is in the last two sentences. How does $X=\{x \in Y : x< \Omega \textrm{ or } x= \Omega\}$ make the set $\{y\in X:y<x\}$ countable?

Comment: We said $\Omega$ was the smallest element such that there were uncountably many elements less than it. Then we went below it.

Comment: @parsiad I just added the page number and the edition.

Comment: @AJY Oh I see. Thanks.

Comment: @AJY One last question. In the proof where it says "Let $\Omega$ be the smallest element in this set", are we using the principle of well-ordering here to make such an assumption?

Comment: Yes. We're saying $\{y \in Y : \{x : x < y\} \textrm{ is uncountable} \}$ is a non-empty subset of $Y$, and since $Y$ is well-ordered this set has a minimum, which we call $\Omega$.